# Sql query to find orders with particular last status

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table called "orders" with the following attributes

**Orders**

*id*

*total*

Another table called order_statuses with the following attributes

**order_statuses**

*id*

*order_id*

*status*

The different statuses are **Pending,Processing, Shipped,Completed**

I am trying to find the orders whose last status is for e.g. **Pending** for a particular year and month

The sql query i tried in laravel is this

```
Order::join('order_statuses','orders.id','=','order_statuses.order_id')->orderBy('order_statuses.id', 'desc')->groupBy('order_statuses.order_id')->where('order_statuses.status','=','Pending')->whereRaw("YEAR(orders.created_at) = ".$year)->whereRaw("MONTH(orders.created_at) = 1")->count()
```

I checked the query and found that if write get() method instead of count() then i am getting some result but its not working for the last status wise. And count function is also not working.

Comment: You can use `whereYear('orders.created_at', '=', $year)` and `whereMonth('orders.created_at', '=', $month)` to avoid using raw sql.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have apostrophe in your query? just delete it and it's working:

```
select * from orders inner join 
order_statuses on (orders.id = order_statuses.order_id)
where order_statuses.status = ? and 
YEAR(orders.created_at) = 2016 and 
MONTH(orders.created_at) = 1 
group by order_statuses.order_id 
order by order_statuses.id desc
```

and you missed an value for your status.